# Asp.net output cache substitution with postback in user control

Tags: asp.net, postback, outputcache, substitution

We have a site where all pages are output cached, i.e. the caching is on aspx-level with VaryByParam="*". Now there is a requirement to make a gallup control, i.e. a small "How is this site working for you?" and then when the user clicks an answer the results are shown.

The gallup is implemented as a usercontrol that is added to the master page so gallups can be added to any page to which a gallup is created in the cms. The problem is that output cache naturally caches all clicks so when user no 2 votes he sees the results that where calculated after the first vote on that alternative.

Now I'm trying to use cache substition. I added an asp:Substition tag where the user control used to be, load the control dynamically and render it (using this approach http://coderwall.com/p/4ajzqq). The problem is that the postbacks that voting triggers is never fired. Apparently the  method that the substition control executes is loaded outside the page life cycle or too late.

Any ideas?

Regards,
Mathias

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by skipping the substitution control and just used the user control as normal, so the gallup/question view was output cached. Then in the click handler for the answer alternatives I added
`Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching();`
which exempted the results view from output cache and hence it was updated as it should.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to use Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching() in Global.asax, using VaryByCustom. It merely requires sensing in Global.asax whether the page is a post-back or not. [Here](https://digitalrumpus.wordpress.com/2015/06/12/use-asp-net-output-caching-safely-with-post-back/) is a code example.